# Get value of input type="button"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the value of Buttons I have created:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="MR" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="MR" name="MR">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="CT" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="CT" name="CT">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="PT" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="PT" name="PT">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="US" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="US" name="US">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use this JS to highlight the button if is pressed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-outline-primary").click(function(){
        $(this).button('toggle');
    });
});
```

Underneath those buttons there is a **submit button**, which I use to search a database. So how can I get the values of the buttons to use them for search (eg. "MR" value)?

Comment: what is `$(this).button('toggle');` ?

Comment: Your question is very ambigious? `<input button` are not send to the server even if you give them a name i think. (on default form submit browser action)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey This is to toggle the button if it's pressed and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"value" is an attribute on the button elements, so you can access it with `.attr()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-outline-primary").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("value"))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="MR" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="MR" name="MR">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="CT" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="CT" name="CT">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="PT" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="PT" name="PT">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="US" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="US" name="US">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(".btn-outline-primary").click(function(){
        console.log($(this).prop('value'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a value of clicked button you can do this. Just use the `value` property of the button to get the `value` associated with the corresponding button.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-outline-primary');

[...buttons].forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log(item.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="MR" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="MR" name="MR">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="CT" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="CT" name="CT">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="PT" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="PT" name="PT">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="US" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="US" name="US">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to store the value for later use then you can simply assign it to some variable.

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-outline-primary');
let clickedValue;

[...buttons].forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    clickedValue = item.value;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a tag , you could always use the `value` method.

## How :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-outline-primary")[0].value;
```

This will get the value of the first element with class `btn-outline-primary`

If you wish to get the values of all elements :

```js
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-outline-primary');
var array = []
arr.map(_=>array.push(_.value))
```

In the case you are using JQuery you will need to add

```
.attr('value')
```

to get the value

Answer (score 0):

You could find all buttons with active class and get their value

Something like:

```
var values = [];
$('.btn-outline-primary.active').each(function(key, value){
 values.push($(this).val());
});
```

values array will have all your values of active buttons